# Static word in c++ showing error

Tags: c++

Linker error: tried to make basic cpp program but there is a linker error saying:unresolved symbol `"private: static int complex::count"`.    When i removed the `static` words, its working fine.

Please find Program sample on this [image: link]

Comment: Share your code here.

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for code formatting help.

Comment: Also you'd better write a deconstructor that decreases `count` by 1.

Answer (score 0):

you must explicitly define your static variable outside of the class. For example like this:

```
class complex {
   ....
   int static count;
   ....
};
// initialization
int complex::count = 0;
```